# Facebook Connect Accessing a User's FB Session/Access Token ID?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have configured my app to correctly allow a user to login via FB Connect 3.1 SDK (for iOS 6), and request email permissions:

```
NSArray *permissons = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"email", nil];
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissons
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
                                    ^(FBSession *session,
                                      FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
            [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
```

Afterwards, I need to determine a user's FB Session ID.  Is this different from the access token?  I believe the Session/Token ID may start with 'AAAFTZCN54f1EBA'?  How may I retrieve this information post-authentication?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are you looking for `FBSession.activeSession.accessToken`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 internetActive=YES;

 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

 // Override point for customization after application launch.

 self.viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

 self.navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

 [self.navController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
 self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
 _internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
 [_internetReachable startNotifier];

 if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
  // Yes, so just open the session (this won't display any UX).
  [self openSession];
 } else {
  // No, display the login page.
  [self showLoginView];
 }

 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
 return YES;
}


-(void)checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
 UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Internet Connection" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
 // called after network status changes
 NetworkStatus internetStatus = [_internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
 switch (internetStatus)
 {
  case NotReachable:
  {
   alert.message=@"The internet is down.";
   internetActive = NO;
   break;
  }
  case ReachableViaWiFi:
  {
   alert.message=@"The internet is working via WIFI.";
   internetActive = YES;
   break;
  }
  case ReachableViaWWAN:
  {
   alert.message=@"The internet is working via WWAN.";
   internetActive = YES;
   break;
  }
 }
 [alert show];
}

#pragma mark- Facebook methods

-(void)getEmailId
{ 
 [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
 return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}


-(void)fblogout{
 NSLog(@"logout called ");
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"fbemail"];
 [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
 [facebook logout];
}
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
 switch (state) {
  case FBSessionStateOpen: {
   UIViewController *topViewController =[self.navController topViewController];
   if ([topViewController isKindOfClass:[Sport_InceptionViewController class]]) {
    [topViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    //    [topViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
  }

   // Initiate a Facebook instance
   facebook = [[Facebook alloc]
                    initWithAppId:FBSession.activeSession.appID
                    andDelegate:nil];

   // Store the Facebook session information
   facebook.accessToken = FBSession.activeSession.accessToken;   **Here is you token**
   facebook.expirationDate = FBSession.activeSession.expirationDate;

   if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"fbemail"]) {
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.viewController.view animated:YES];
    [self getEmailId];
   }

   break;
  case FBSessionStateClosed:
  case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
   // Once the user has logged in, we want them to
   // be looking at the root view.
   [self.navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

   [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
   facebook = nil;

   [self showLoginView];
   break;
  default:
   break;
 }

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
  postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
  object:session];

 if (error) {
  UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Error"
                            message:error.localizedDescription
                            delegate:nil
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alertView show];
 }
}

- (void)openSession
{
 if (internetActive) {
  NSArray *permissions=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream",@"email",nil];

  [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler: ^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
   [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
  }];
 }else
 {
  UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Internet Not Connected" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
 }
}

#pragma mark- request delegate methods 

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
{
  NSLog(@"request did load successfully....");

//  __block NSDictionary *dictionary=[[NSDictionary alloc] init];

 if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
  NSDictionary* json = result;

  NSLog(@"email id is %@",[json valueForKey:@"email"]);
  NSLog(@"json is %@",json);

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[json valueForKey:@"email"] forKey:@"fbemail"];
  [self.viewController login:YES];
 }
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Server not responding.." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

 [alertView show];

 [self fblogout];
 [self showLoginView];
 NSLog(@"request did fail with error");
}


- (void)showLoginView
{
    UIViewController *topViewController = [self.navController topViewController];

    if (![topViewController isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]]) {

        MyViewController *loginViewController=[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
        [topViewController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else {
        MyViewController* loginViewController=(MyViewController*)topViewController;
        [loginViewController loginFailed];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the "Facebook" class? I don't see it in their docs, and it's not in the framework.